# Dropdown in kendo-ui grid erase text after validation, how to fix that?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown

I have a kendo-ui grid in witch I have 2 columns: username and a role. The role column when I edit is a dropdown. The grid has a validation: I don't can have a username with the same role. All looks god until a scenario don't work: when I set a username and a role that already exists, the validation comes (until here it's ok), after that when I select an other role (that is valid) the record is added to the grid but the username is removed. I don't understand why. I started from this example: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Jkkw8/100/) (also with [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/problems-with-data-binding-dropdownlist-in-grid))
I tried to set al my code in a [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/59nb8tr1/), but I don't know why It don't load.

Here is my code:

```
            var roles = [
            {role: "SYSTEM_USER", roleId: 1},
            {role: "COMPONENT_EDITOR", roleId: 2},
            {role: "CHANGE_REQUEST_EDITOR", roleId: 3}
        ];


$(document).ready(function() {
var permissionDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                dataType: "json",
                data: this.model.get("permissions"),
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "userName",
                        fields: {
                            userName: {
                                type: "text",
                                editable: true,
                                validation: {
                                    required: true,
                                    roleIsUniqueValidation: function (input){
                                        if (input.is("[name='userName']")) {
                                            var currentUserName = input.val();
                                            var currentRole = $($(this.element.children()[1]).children()).children().text();
                                            var currentId = this.element.data("uid");
                                            var elements = $("#kendoGrid").data().kendoGrid.dataSource.view();

                                            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

                                                var el = elements[i];

                                                // exclude from checks the current row
                                                if (el.uid != currentId) {

                                                    // check if there are docs with the same type and number combination
                                                    if (el.userName == currentUserName && el.role == currentRole) {
                                                        input.attr("data-roleIsUniqueValidation-msg", "Role already exists for this user");
                                                        return false;
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        return true;

                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            role: {
                                defaultValue: {role: "SYSTEM_USER", roleId: 1}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }});

        // transform grid to kendogrid
        $("#kendoGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: permissionDataSource,
            sortable: true,
            scrollable: true,
            height:300,
            dataBound: function (){
               thisView._resizeKendoGrid();
            },
            editable: {
                mode: "inline"
            },
            columns: [{
                field: "userName",
                title: "Username"
                }, {
                    field: "role",
                    title: "Role",
                    template: "#=role#",
                    width: 240,
                    editor: rolesDropDownEditor
                },
                {
                    title: "#", 
                    command: [{
                        name: "edit",
                        text: { update: "Add"}
                    },{
                        name: "destroy"
                        }
                    ],
                hidden: true
                }]

            });
}
function categoryDropDownEditor(container, options) {
$('<input data-text-field="CategoryName" data-value-field="CategoryID" data-value-field="CategoryName" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: false,
    dataSource: {
        data: categories                    
    }
});
```

}

What exactly I'm doing wrong? I think the template, but I'm not sure.

Comment: where is the rolesDropDownEditor

Answer (score 0):

You should use this dropdown editor :

```
function rolesDropDownEditor(container, options) {
$('<input data-text-field="roleId" data-value-field="role" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
.appendTo(container).kendoDropDownList({
autoBind: true,
dataSource: {
    data: roles                    
}
});
}
```

Also provide data that you are passing to grid, so that it could be tested better.